# Can we have 2 APIgateway for one NLB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-vpc, nlb

We have 2 internal service in a single VPC that is open to internet via

- APIgateway(Regional)
- Vpc link.

For green blue deployment APIGateway is only **fix point** for us.

Now one of the service have to talk to other service, and we do that via hitting APIgateway, and because the other service is within a VPC we have to use proxy to connect to that APIgateway(Regional). But we still need a Regional APIgateway as we have other service outside the VPC.

Service `A` -> Proxy -> Regional API Gateway of Service `B`

---

Now the question is can we have a `Private APIgateway` also `Regional APIgateway` working in parallel and hit the same ECS service?
In this case we will not have to go via proxy at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A VPCLink can be reused across numerous API Gateway endpoints, this will work as long as the API Gateway and Network Load Balancer are within the same account.

> The Network Load Balancer and API must be owned by the same AWS account.

Comment: Sure, will try. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: No problem, hope it goes well for you :D

Comment: @ChrisWilliams I tried adding two api gw to single nlb and faced error "Failed to stabilize Vpc Link with id jari5r Status Message NLB is already associated with another VPC Endpoint Service"

Comment: @sudiptdabral how did you fix it?

Comment: As Chris mentioned, when we create API GW it asks for VPCLink and in VPC Link we need to provide NLB, we can reuse existing NLB.