# Can we have 2 VPC Link associated with same NLB

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk

I am trying to create API Gatweway via CDK, but the ECS Service I have is already associated with another VPC Link which is for a API Gateway via Console.

Now, I want to associate the New VPC Link which is via CDK to that ECS Service but I am getting that NLB is already associated with another service.

Is there any way I can achieve this.

Referring this [Can we have 2 APIgateway for one NLB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64719850/can-we-have-2-apigateway-for-one-nlb) seems not to work since I have the same account for CDK and console.

Comment: Why can't you create everything from CDK NLB, ECS, API-GW and ignore the one created by Console? That way it will be much clear implementation without conflicts.

Comment: We had created via console last year and it is serving production for our app